# SwiftUI ForEach loop multiple arrays

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to `ForEach` loop some `array`'s of `array`'s of json data in SwiftUI. I used https://app.quicktype.io to get my data struct from this URL [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sileo/featuredpage/gh-pages/featured-iphone-src.json).

I'm looking to get classes `FeaturedHeaderView` and `FeaturedPackageView`, which have title's of "Hot Right Now" and "What We're Using" which also contain the `FeaturedPackageView` data. My problem is I'm only looping through the first `FeaturedHeaderView` and  `FeaturedPackageView` repeatedly, which I assumed there was two for each section. Is my `data struct` incorrect? I've never attempted complex json data yet, so I'm unsure how to handle it properly and if the `ForEach` loop is what I'm looking for. The end goal would be to have a `List` with `"Hot Right Now" and it's items and then then "What We're Using" and it's items.

I was able to get the `FeaturedBannersView` class just fine using two `ForEach` loops and thought it would be the same approach for the rest of the data?

[image: Banner View]

**The banner view working**

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack {
        ForEach(self.welcome.views,  id: \.viewClass) { views in
            ForEach(views.banners ?? [], id:\.url) { banner in
                ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        RequestImage(Url(banner.url), animation: nil)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                            .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(CGFloat(views.itemCornerRadius ?? 0))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(banner.title ?? "")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 15)
                }
                .frame(width: 263, height: 148)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.leading, 10)
    .padding(.trailing, 10)
}
```

**The issue**

[image: Issue]

My data struct

```swift
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let views: [WelcomeView]
}

struct WelcomeView: Codable {
    let viewClass: String?
    let banners: [Banner]?
    let views: [PurpleView]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case views
    }
}

struct Banner: Codable {
    let url: String?
    let title, package, repoName: String?
}

struct PurpleView: Codable {
    let viewClass: String?
    let views: [FluffyView]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case views
    }
}

struct FluffyView: Codable {
    let viewClass: String?
    let title: String?
    let package, packageName, packageAuthor: String?
    let repoName: RepoName?
    let packageIcon: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case title, package, packageName, packageAuthor, repoName, packageIcon
    }
}

enum RepoName: String, Codable {
    case chariz = "Chariz"
    case packix = "Packix"
}
```

```swift
List {
    ForEach(self.welcome.views, id: \.viewClass) { view in
        ForEach(view.views ?? [], id: \.viewClass) { purple in
            ForEach(purple.views, id: \.packageName) { fluffy in
                if fluffy.viewClass == "FeaturedHeaderView" {
                    Text(fluffy.title ?? "")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                } else {
                    HStack (spacing: 15){
                        RequestImage(Url(fluffy.packageIcon ?? ""), animation: nil)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(13.5)
                        VStack (alignment: .leading){
                            Text(fluffy.packageName ?? "")
                                .font(.body)
                            Text(fluffy.packageAuthor ?? "")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                .font(.callout)
                            Text(fluffy.repoName?.rawValue ?? "")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.onAppear() {
    request()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting the repeats is that you're using `.viewClass` and `.packageName` as your ids for the `ForEach` loops, but in the JSON, those values are **not** actually unique.  `FeaturedStackView`, for example, gets repeated.

### How to solve it:

Add IDs to your models and use them for the `ForEach` keys.

```
// MARK: - WelcomeView
struct WelcomeView: Codable {
    var id = UUID() //<-- HERE
    let viewClass: String
    let itemSize: String?
    let itemCornerRadius: Int?
    let banners: [Banner]?
    let horizontalSpacing: Int?
    let views: [PurpleView]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case itemSize, itemCornerRadius, banners, horizontalSpacing, views
    }
}

struct PurpleView: Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let viewClass: String
    let preferredWidth: Int
    let views: [FluffyView]
    let xPadding: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case preferredWidth, views, xPadding
    }
}

struct FluffyView: Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let viewClass: String
    let title: String?
    let useBoldText: Bool?
    let package, packageName, packageAuthor: String?
    let repoName: RepoName?
    let packageIcon: String?
    let orientation: String?
    let views: [TentacledView]?
    let text: String?
    let action: String?
    let yPadding: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case viewClass = "class"
        case title, useBoldText, package, packageName, packageAuthor, repoName, packageIcon, orientation, views, text, action, yPadding
    }
}
```

Then, in each of your `ForEach` loops, use `id: \.id`